# How to implement XMPP server in java so as to get upstream messages from GCM server ?

Tags: java, android, server, google-cloud-messaging, xmpp

I have already implemented client side on android, 
android device gets device token and then send it directly to App server using sockets
But I read, that it's better to use XMPP and send message first to GCM server, which then send it to App server

How to implement XMPP server in java? Where do I have to put my server ? 
I mean, GCM has to have possibility to achieve my App server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking to implement one yourself ? If not, consider this list:

- [Openfire](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/)
- [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/xmpp-server-ref)
- [ejabberd](https://www.ejabberd.im)

Comment: I want to use Firebase, and I have found an example of code of the server side - http://www.grokkingandroid.com/xmpp-server-google-cloud-messaging/
Could you give me advice, how  should I deploy this server or put it on hosting so as to Google Cloud messaging server will see it ?